# JSF inlclude parameter in url after form post

Tags: jsf, parameters, submit

I have a pare which is requires a GET-paremeter (int id).
is also has  with some textfields (for filtering)

```
<h:form> 
  //some textfields
  <h:commandButton value="Anwenden" actionListener="#{bean.acceptFilters}" action="">
      <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.logbookId}" />
  </h:commandButton>
<h:form>
```

Now, I have two problems:

1. I need somehow a GET-Request to allow bookmarking of the search results (like Google)
2. The parameter "id" is also not passed in the URL when i post the form (but is required)

The parameters in the url are lost when i click submit... internally they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a GET button instead of a POST button. Get rid of the word "command" in the component (and if necessary also the POST form if it isn't been used for other purposes).

```
<h:button value="Anwenden" outcome="nextpage">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.logbookId}" />
</h:button>
```

In order to supplant the `actionListener`, do the job in (post)constructor or `preRenderView` listener of the managed bean associated with `nextpage.xhtml`.

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)
- [Bookmarkability via View Parameters feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249844/bookmarkability-via-view-parameters-feature/)

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for your help; Is it with h:button also possible to send the text-fields' content via get-parameter? because that was the reason i used a form

Comment: No. Just use a regular `<form>` with `<input type="submit">` instead of `<h:form>` with `<h:commandButton>`.

Comment: Thanks, so is this the preferred way to specify navigation? as already mentioned I'd like that the user can specify a filter, which is sent by GET to the same page to do filtering?

Comment: There is no "better" way. Just use the right tool for the job. See also the "See also" links for an elaboration on that.