# Why should I navigate from POST to GET using REDIRECT?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, post-redirect-get

Below is an extract of book "JSF 2.0: The Complete Reference" (also seen on [Ed Burns' blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/post_redirect_get_and_jsf)):

> Michael Jouravlev, in his influential August 2004 article [Redirect After Post](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post), described a problem that many web applications present. He described the problem as follows:
>
> > All interactive programs provide *two* basic functions: obtaining user input and displaying the results. Web applications implement this behavior using two HTTP methods: `POST` and `GET` respectively. This simple protocol gets broken when an application returns a web page in response to a `POST` request. Peculiarities of the POST method combined with idiosyncrasies of different browsers often lead to an unpleasant user experience and may produce an incorrect state of the server application.
>
> To address the problem, Jouravlev described a technique that he called `POST-REDIRECT-GET`, or the PRG pattern for short. The rules of the pattern are as follows:
>
> > - Never show pages in response to `POST`
> > - Always load pages using `GET`
> > - Navigate from `POST` to `GET` using `REDIRECT`
>
> We have seen that JSF violates the first of these rules by using POST for every page
>   navigation via the `RequestDispatcher.forward()` method from the Servlet API. Indeed,
>   most popular Java Servlet–based Web frameworks, including Struts, use this approach for
>   navigation. HTTP purists rightly point out that this approach violates the first rule in the
>   PRG pattern. Not only did JSF violate the first rule, but until JSF 2.0, it was very difficult to
>   do it any other way. Thanks to another JSF contribution from the Seam team at JBoss, it is
>   now much easier to do PRG with JSF.

First of all, I have failed to make myself explain the problem that he was trying to address. 
(how the protocol gets broken when an application returns a web page in response to a POST request)

Secondly, even though I know very well what redirect, `POST` & `GET` means, I am facing problem what will, in essence, force me to navigate from `POST` to `GET` using `REDIRECT` and why should I as (extract of book "JSF 2.0: The Complete Reference" continued):

> Whether or not to use redirects largely depends on whether what is
>   shown in the address bar of the browser matters or could be confusing
>   if the page referenced no longer matches the page being rendered.
>   Another important consideration of when to use redirects is
>   performance. Using a redirect will terminate the current request and
>   cause a new request response cycle to occur. If the page has a very
>   large set of components, this could have a noticeable performance
>   impact. Redirects can also necessitate an extra round trip to
>   reinstantiate any request-scoped objects that have disappeared by the
>   next request.

Comment: It describes the story about the PRG design pattern. What do you want others to do with it particularly in their answer(s)?

Comment: @Tiny: OP failed to put citations in blockquotes with references to original sources, hereby making his question completely confusing. I tidied up it.

Comment: @Shirgill: the key answer is "idempotence" aka "bookmarkability". This is fleshed out in the answer of among others the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451 (also check out the "See also" section at the bottom of that answer) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13249844. Which one do you accept as duplicate?